# How to sign a SOAP request multiple times using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, soap, xml-signature

I am new to SOAP and I need to use it here.

I am trying to send a SOAP request to an external endpoint.
For it to work I have to sign the SOAP request multiple times using certificates and encrypt it.
I tried the [node-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) package using the *WSSecurityCert* function giving it the private key, public key and the password but this only lets me sign it once. 
Using the function *setSecurity* twice didn't add two signatures.

How I understand it the soap package lets you configure everything but only creates the XML in the end. That means I can only view the created XML after I have sent it.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to only sign the XML and get it back and then sign it again and encrypt everything in the end? Doing the process manually.
- Are there any other active packages or ways to achive this using nodejs?

Comment: how many times must it be signed?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
const soap = require('soap');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// SOAP request payload
const soapRequest = {
  // Your SOAP request content
};

function signSoapEnvelope(soapEnvelope) {
  // Your signing logic here
  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
  soapEnvelope.Header = {
    Timestamp: timestamp,
    // Other headers...
  };

  // You may also want to sign the SOAP body or other parts as needed
  // ...

  return soapEnvelope;
}

soap.createClient(url, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  let signedSoapRequest = signSoapEnvelope(soapRequest);
  signedSoapRequest = signSoapEnvelope(signedSoapRequest); // you could sign it here again
  client.MySoapOperation(signedSoapRequest, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    } 
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but the part I am struggling with is the "// Your signing logic here". I know I can set the signing information with the WSSecurity + setSecurity in the client and it will be later applied to my request via node-soap. 
I am struggling to find a solution that generates a signature for me and returns my signed XML directly which I would use in your example. Or is it alternatively possible to create signatures manually using the crypto package? I can see that you imported it but It wasn't used in the example.